# Linq statement using where in

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first

I am looking to get a list of all the distinct friends and friends of friends in the network. Then I want to take that list and pull all the new signups for those people since X date. I have read a bunch online about how to use linq for a sql 'where in' clause but I am unable to apply it the way ive found demonstrated. The current code also does not return the full agent, just what I have selected. I am only selecting specific data because I cannot seem to grab a distinct list if it returns the full agent record. To add to the issue, now that I have made this a anon type that is returned my signup query cant run against it. What would be the best way for me to achieve this?

Key Issues:

- I need to return the full model of the agent but distinct
- I need to pull the newest signups for the collected agents above preferably using a 'where in' clause so I don't have to do a loops that hits the db a million times.

**Grabs a distinct list of people in network**

```
var network = agent.Friends.Where(f => f.FriendAgent != null)
                .SelectMany(f => f.FriendAgent.Friends
                    .Select(c => c.FriendAgent)
                    .Where(x => x != null))
                    .Distinct<NPlay.Common.Models.Agent>(new TestEquality())
                .Take(100).ToList();
```

**^--- Resolved using the method described by Jared in the answers ---^**

**Selects newest signups since X date**

```
var query =
                from s in _signupRepository.List.OrderByDescending(s=>s.Created).Where(s => s.Created >= startDate && s.Created <= endDate && !s.Canceled.HasValue)
                where network.Contains(s.Membership)
                select s;
```

The Contains just doesnt seem right to me but there was no other way for me to use it that was remotely close to what I was looking for :/

**Resolved**
Removed Id now that the top was setup and it works :)

Comment: Why do you have `dynamic` instead of `var`?

Comment: small detail, i was going to add dynamic properties to it but that can change i am not hardset on the type. i have made an email template processor system and it uses dynamics, the end model from the whole method will be a dynamic but this particular call does not have to be. since i 'fixed' the first query the project doesnt compile because of it being an anon type, not that it worked before :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your first problem you can pass `Distinct()` an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that tells it how to compare the objects. That way you can select your `Friend` instead of an anonymous object.

```
public class TestEquality : IEqualityComparer<Friend>
{
    public bool Equals(Friend x, Friend y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name; // or however you determine equality
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Friend obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

using `network.Contains(s.Membership.Id)` will generate a sql where in, have you looked at the sql that is generated?

Comment: Thanks Jared, this seems to have worked for the first query. I will work on the 2nd part and see if I can get it wired up. Didn't realize I could pass in the compare it worked well. @user2674389, I am using this in Linqpad against my repo class that uses EF and it seems to be working, perhaps this will be different when I run it through the project.